# I can't adjust the MVC5 Bootstrap TextAreaFor Width

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm struggling for hours now to render a notes field to have full width and a few rows on a  bootstrap tab. What I want is this:
[image]

What I have done so far is looking for solutions/posts but none is working for me. My razor-code is:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="notes">
<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project.sysNotes, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Project.sysNotes, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Project.sysNotes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project.sysUser_Add, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Project.sysUser_Add, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Project.sysUser_Add, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project.sysDD_Add, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Project.sysDD_Add, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Project.sysDD_Add, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I adjusted the css files (bootstrap, bootstrap-sandstone and site) to resp.:

```
textarea.form-control {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;}
```

and

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default (LC: was 280px)*/
input,
select,
textarea {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

What can I do???

edit: see also comment below @T_Roy, the new screendump:
[image]

Maybe, does the wrongly rendering has to do with the _layout.cshtml?

edit (last time): I accept the answer of T_Roy, the way to go, but what eventually solved my current problem was the add-on (hack) of Laiman. I still see strange behavior in my solution but it works and need to go on now. I will have to refactor however and gain more understanding of how it all works together.

Thank you all!

Comment: Try setting the containing div's class to `col-md-12`

Comment: updated solution with info to override Bootstrap MVC form default [div] classes, which were capping width of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So taking this a little deeper so that you can understand how this works.

First off, a `row` element can have up to `12` columns.

> [Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

For example, using what you provided:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project.sysUser_Add, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Project.sysUser_Add, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Project.sysUser_Add, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project.sysDD_Add, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Project.sysDD_Add, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Project.sysDD_Add, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your `labels` each have a class named `col-md-2` meaning they take up 2 columns in the row.. so since you have 2 labels (`model.Project.sysUser_Add`, and `model.Project.sysDD_Add`), you are really taking up **4** columns in the row.  So you have **8** columns left before that row is filled to capacity.  So your `TextBoxFor` account for those 8 columns because your `TextBoxFor`'s each are inside a `div` which have classes named `col-md-4`. 4 + 4 = 8.

Now taking that logic and applying it to your `TextAreaFor`.

You have a label which has a class of `col-md-2`, so you have **10** columns left before that row is filled to capacity.  As of now, your `TextAreaFor` is inside a `div` that is `col-md-8`.  **8 + 2 = 10**.  You still have **2** columns to use before that row is filled.  So change the `div` that your `TextAreaFor` is inside to `col-md-10`.  **10 + 2 = 12**.  That should adjust your `TextAreaFor` to use the full-width to match your `TextBoxFor`s.

Here is a working [demo](https://www.bootply.com/zC2T7m60dU).

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Hi @T_Roy, after playing around some time I stripped down the example ti this:
`<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project.sysNotes, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Project.sysNotes, new { @class = "form-control col-md-10" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
`
and even that doesn't work. A add screenshot to the question

Comment: You are putting the `col-md-10` in the wrong place.  The `@Html.TextAreaFor` does not need any classes dealing with `col`.  In your original example.. you have a `div` above the `TextAreaFor` that is `col-md-8`.. change that to `col-md-10`

Comment: Sure wish that `demo` link still worked. (Well, I wish it worked for me. Maybe it's my Work box that can't get to it.)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using actually using bootstrap grids, rows and columns as mentioned by *T_Roy*. [See](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp)

For your own css solution you can do this. Add the class **long-width** in the TextArea input

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Project.sysNotes, new { @class = "form-control long-width" })
```

Then apply this css:

```
.long-width {
  min-width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: Laiman, should I put the class in the site.css? Given my BundleConfig.cs:
`bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap-sandstone.css",
            "~/Content/site.css"));
`

Comment: That is up to you, if you would be needing it often you should put it in the site.css. You can also use internal css <style>...</style> if it is a one off thing.

Comment: The internal style did the trick (more or less ;). In your opinion where do I look to solve this because it is not a one off thing

Comment: Okay. Put it in the site.css file and call the class when ever you need it. Also if this solved your question then please mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: but when I put it in the site.css it didn't work. I'm really puzzled. And yes I'm new to mvc (and razor and css and...)

Comment: Make sure you rebuild the project to make sure it has loaded the added css. That can happen sometimes. Also try to clear browser history as some browsers (Chrome) tend to use saved css styling, that happened to me before.

Answer (score 0):

change `col-md-8` to `col-md-10` it will make it `width: 100%`

Comment: If the OP sets the column to be `col-md-12` then their label will no longer be on the side of the text-area.  It will be above it, because the textarea now takes up the entire space of the `row`

Comment: oh sorry it should be 10

Comment: do u have it hosted anyhwere? or live?

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation ([Link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)) row classes should be inside of container classes.

Comment: This answer does not help the OP in finding a solution to their problem.

Answer (score -1):

VS 2017 Solution

if you want to target just one object, you can add it directly into the new {} properties.. textarea width is controlled by cols property, so original HTML would balance percentage based items out to 100%, so 40-40-40% would equate to 33-33-33% or ~100% of the object they are inside of.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Project.sysNotes
    , new { @class = "form-control", @rows="3",  @cols = "40%" })
```

## Bootstrap

Bootstrap was a whole other animal.. took a few days for me to figure out what was capping the width on objects found inside generated forms..

3 related items. can be referenced that are related to generated [div]s : .form-control, .form-group & .form-row. *** I switched all my form-group objects to form-row objects, because they leave less space between rows than form-group objects do, so less scrolling.

Add this into your style sheet to allow max-width.. then you can override the width on the [div]s you want to shrink.

```
<style>
    .form-control {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    .form-group {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    .form-row {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }

</style>
```

then override the code in the [div] you wish to shrink.

```
<div class="form-row" style="width: 320px">
```